# How to align buttons on row using stack views without growing label

Tags: macos, stackview, nsstackview

I have 3 buttons and I want to align them to left and right. Previously I was using growing label to align them. **Is there a way how to achieve this without growing label?**

What `distribution + hugging priorities` etc. should I use to get correct configuration as on pic?

PS : **StackView** is pinned to left, bottom, right.

[image]

Comment: Yes , Set 4 label in stack view with alignment left. Using fill proportionally you can manage easily which you want.

Comment: @AnjaliShah there is no alignment left on macos for horizontal stack view